# Simultaneous IIS .NET web service calls gets wrong user context after returning from a subroutine

Tags: .net, servicestack, iis-10

Thanks to some extensive logging I added to our IIS/Servicestack/.NET Web API for a different problem I found some very troubling behavior while looking into a reported issue.

Keep in mind that when I added the logging I created a GUID upon entry to the route to track the process of the calls in a log table dedicated to this one route. I log most entry and exit from subroutines in the route as well as important waypoints, and I have the stored procedures calls also write to the log table, all with this unique GUID and other user information, timestamp, and so on.

There were two different users, user A and user B, both hitting the same route at nearly the same time. The route performs some database manipulation and returns a value.  User A arrived first and the process made a subroutine call (R1) which called another subroutine (R2) that performed a query with `command.ExecuteScalar()`.  The query was a call to a stored procedure. While this query was running (which takes less then 1 sec) User B hits the route, B's process calls subroutine R1 which calls subroutine R2 which executes the query with `command.ExecuteScalar()`.  The queries are identical in that they call the same stored procedure but have different user specific parameters.

At this point User A and User B are both waiting down in R2 for their calls to `command.ExecuteScalar()` to complete.

Milliseconds later User A's DB call completes, so User A's process exists subroutine R2, back into subroutine R1 and it immediately writes some information to the log table, but the information it writes is the GUID of User B (!). It seems that when R2 completed and returned control to R1, the context of R1 for User A was now User B's. User A's process now has the wrong local environment for R1 (the sub routine parameters are now B's), so when it tries to query the database to get results it fails (because it is using B's data and B's initial db call has not yet completed).  So User A's process exists with a failure condition.  Interestingly, when User A's process exits R1 and returns to caller R0 the context is now correct (as evidenced by log entries).  So only R1's context for User A was incorrect after the return from R2.

Milliseconds later User B's database call completes, it's R2 exits back to R1 and it writes to the log with it's own correct context.  User B's process is able to continue without error.

I'm trying to determine where this kind of failure can occur, is this an IIS issue, a Servicestack issue, a .NET issue, server memory corruption or something else?  Each user should have their own worker thread, how can the contexts be corrupted in this way?

If this is a one-off event then fine, but that it can happen at all disturbs me greatly.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

Here is a partial listing of the cleansed log, it goes from newest to oldest.

```
09, 16:21:45.460, B, 223E72C9-F142-4844-BD6E-C805E4C0EBBA, ...Additional processing
08, 16:21:45.457, B, 223E72C9-F142-4844-BD6E-C805E4C0EBBA, R3 Success
07, 16:21:45.417, B, 223E72C9-F142-4844-BD6E-C805E4C0EBBA, CALL R3
06, 16:21:45.207, B, 223E72C9-F142-4844-BD6E-C805E4C0EBBA, SP Exits
05, 16:21:45.353, A, D4F1AA08-6735-4335-9BB5-62723B2AA2A7, R0 Exit
04, 16:21:45.350, A, D4F1AA08-6735-4335-9BB5-62723B2AA2A7, R0 Fails
03, 16:21:45.283, B, 223E72C9-F142-4844-BD6E-C805E4C0EBBA, R3 Fails (exits R1)
02, 16:21:45.247, B, 223E72C9-F142-4844-BD6E-C805E4C0EBBA, CALL R3
01, 16:21:40.920, A, D4F1AA08-6735-4335-9BB5-62723B2AA2A7, SP Exits
```

At 01 User A's stored proc ends.
Line 02 show user B's process calling R3, which occurs after the stored procedure ends. This should be User A.
Note on line 04, after R1 returns a failure to R0, the context is now correct for User A.
Line 06 is User B's stored procedure ending.
Lines 07-on are User B normally processing the result.

Line 02-03 should have been User A's data, if it had it would have been successful

Comment: Do you have a static variable somewhere? That's where my mind first went.

Comment: @matt - No, all params are passed into subroutine R1 from R0.  I've gone over it a lot, the log, the code, as crazy as it sounds the 'system' giving me the wrong context is the only explanation that fits, but I don't want to get locked into that way of thinking...